# Clicking of URLs outside of browser does not open up

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, skype, url

Nothing happens when I click on a URL outside of a browser. Chrome is my default browser but it does not do anything if I click on a link in e.g. Skype. What can cause this?

---

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol
    AppUserModelID    REG_SZ    Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default
    EditFlags    REG_DWORD    0x2
    FriendlyTypeName    REG_SZ    @C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll,-903
    Source Filter    REG_SZ    {E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}
    URL Protocol    REG_SZ
    WebNavigableCLSID    REG_SZ    {ae90e550-0443-47fb-a001-4875648d4ed3}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\DefaultIcon
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe,0

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\Extensions
    .ASF    REG_SZ    {187463A0-5BB7-11D3-ACBE-0080C75E246E}
    .WM    REG_SZ    {187463A0-5BB7-11D3-ACBE-0080C75E246E}
    .WMA    REG_SZ    {187463A0-5BB7-11D3-ACBE-0080C75E246E}
    .WMV    REG_SZ    {187463A0-5BB7-11D3-ACBE-0080C75E246E}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell
    (Default)    REG_SZ    open

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\ddeexec
    (Default)    REG_SZ
    NoActivateHandler    REG_SZ

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\ddeexec\Application
    (Default)    REG_SZ    IExplore

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\ddeexec\Topic
    (Default)    REG_SZ    WWW_OpenURL
```

Comment: Post here values from registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http`, you may use this command in `cmd.exe`, `reg query HKCR\http /s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry Chrome was set properly as the default browser for ftp, http and https, however in Control Panel/Default Programs it was "Unknown application" (or something like that). Setting Firefox and then Chrome back as the default didn't solved it so I had to reinstall Chrome. That worked.

---

If you are encountering a problem similar to this, the following question has a great answer related to this topic:
[How do I change my default browser to an unlisted program in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/368814/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser-to-an-unlisted-program-in-windows-7)