# How to change default browser to custom program/script (http-association) in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, autohotkey

How do I change the default browser in Windows 8.1 to a custom program or script?

I would like to change the association of the http-protocol to an AutoHotKey-Script (AHK), which opens the right browser based on the URL.

In Windows 7 some registry tweaks helped, like described here: [How do I change my default browser to an unlisted program in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/368814/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser-to-an-unlisted-program-in-windows-7)

In Windows 8.1 the registry key for the file-assoc still exists...

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" -osint -url \"%1\""
```

...but is overridden by this "UserChoice" setting

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"ProgId"="FirefoxURL"
"Hash"="...."
```

If I remove the entry mentioned above, the dialog "How do you want to open this type of link (http)" occurs, but there is no "More options..." setting in the footer. So how can I point to my AHK-Script or any other unlisted program?

Directly editing the values in the UserChoice-Key doesn't take effect (Dialog to choose browser opens again). I suppose this is due to the "Hash" securing those entries.

Is there any "vanilla registry editing" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found a solution that works for me. So anybody stumbling on this question, perhaps finds this useful.

To make your own script availabe in the  Set Program Access and Computer Defaults (SPAD) tool, it has to be registered in three sections of the registry.

1. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
2. RegisteredApplications
3. StartMenuInternet

(see sample below for complete path)

- In **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** you have to specify the command to be executed, I called it *yourCustomScriptURL* in the sample below.
- **RegisteredApplications** tells windows that your script exists and points to the 3rd registry section.
- **StartMenuInternet**, the 3rd and last section you have to add, tells Windows that your script can handle http and https protocol and points to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT entry.

Microsoft documented the steps necessary under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

And if you put everything together it looks like this.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\yourCustomScriptURL]
@="yourCustomScript"
"FriendlyTypeName"="yourCustomScript"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\yourCustomScriptURL\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\yourCustomScriptURL\shell\open\command]
@="\"<...path to AHK...>\\AutoHotkey.exe\" \"<...path to script...>\\yourCustomScript.ahk\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RegisteredApplications]
"yourCustomScript"="Software\\Clients\\StartMenuInternet\\yourCustomScript\\Capabilities"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\yourCustomScript]
@="yourCustomScript"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\yourCustomScript\Capabilities\StartMenu]
"StartMenuInternet"="yourCustomScript"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\yourCustomScript\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"http"="yourCustomScriptURL"
"https"="yourCustomScriptURL"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work under Windows 10. The link you mentioned says as much but the link that MS further provides doesn't include any technical details. The error I get is:

`Something unexpected went wrong with this URL: "<the URL>", <the URL again> is not a valid Win32 application.`

This happens even if I don't include %1 as an argument in the command string.